# Filter based on pairs within a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, filter

```
 Group Code
   1     2
   1     2
   1     4
   1     1
   2     4 
   2     1
   2     2 
   2     3
   2     1
   2     1
   2     3
```

Within each group there are pairs. In Group 1 for example; the pairs are (2,2),(2,4),(4,1)

I want to filter these pairs based on code number 2 being present at the beginning of the pair.
In group 1 for example, only (2,2) and (2,4) will be kept while (4,1) will be filtered out.

Excepted Output:

```
 Group Code
   1     2
   1     2
   1     4
   2     2 
   2     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `groupby` `shift`

```
out = df[df.groupby('Group').Code.apply(lambda x : x.eq(2) | x.eq(2).shift())]
Out[67]: 
   Group  Code
0      1     2
1      1     2
2      1     4
6      2     2
7      2     3
```

Comment: Apply can be avoided: `df[df.groupby("Group")['Code'].shift().eq(2)|df['Code'].eq(2)]`

Comment: @BENY Can I use this with multiple code numbers? 2 AND 4 being present for example?

Comment: @tjjudge `df[df.groupby('Group').Code.apply(lambda x : x.isin([2,4]) | x.isin([2,4].shift())]`